# Text classification of inconsistent regulatory material for regulatory requirements

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Hi I am new to tensorflow and tensorflowHub for that matter and would like to know what I should be using from the API considering my text classification use case.

I want to find out the housing setback information for different municipalities. Using Python I have web **scraped** the info successfully and used NLTK to classify the words but I want to take it a step further and use ML given no two municipality codes are alike! As an example one municipality may have something like this:

> Setback requirements.

> - Minimum front setback: 25 feet.
> - Minimum side setback from a street right-of-way: 25 feet.
> - Minimum side setback from an interior lot line: five feet.
> - Minimum rear setback for principal uses: 25 feet.
> - Minimum rear setback for accessory uses: ten feet.

etc

While another may have the following text.

> For all R-1 districts except 4-R-1, the minimum setbacks shall be as follows:

> 1. Front. No building or structure shall be located within fifty (50) feet of the centerline of any street nor twenty (20) feet of the property line, whichever is greater.
> 2. There shall be a side yard setback on each side of the parcel equal to ten percent (10%) of the width of the parcel. In no case shall the minimum required side yard setback be less than five (5) feet. In order to preserve architectural integrity, the side yard setback required for an addition to an existing building or structure may be permitted to utilize the established setback, provided that the established side yard setback is not less than five (5) feet.
> 3. Rear. There shall be a rear yard setback of not less than fifteen (15) feet.

> For the 4-R-1 district, the minimum setbacks shall be as follows:

> 1. Front. No building or structure shall be located within forty (40) feet of the centerline of any street nor ten (10) feet of the property line, whichever is greater.
> 2. Side. Three (3) feet.
> 3. Rear. Fifteen (15) feet.

etc

**How can I classify this text on the required setbacks that each municipality requires? I eventually want to use this in ARCgis as a shape file or similiar.**
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a challenging modelling task given that I assume there is not much data from a given municipality and not a lot of standardization between municipalities.

If the amount of data is available would support it, you could try fine-tuning one of the existing transformers (https://tfhub.dev/google/collections/transformer_encoders_text/1) using the same pre-training objective that was used to train them in the first place, e.g. masked language model (MLM).

In general, tensorflow-hub might not be the best tag to get a general modeling advice since tfhub.dev is a repository of pretrained models published by the OSS community.